# C++ templates and OpenBLAS

Tags: c++, eigen, lapack, blas, boost-ublas

There exist C++ libraries such as Eigen or Boost::uBlas that implement matrix types and computations.

There also exist libraries such as LAPACK, Goto-BLAS, OpenBLAS and ATLAS that implement highly optimized dense matrix computations over floating-point types.

I was wondering whether some C++ libraries, perhaps through specialization, call OpenBLAS for the types supported by OpenBLAS. It would seem the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Boost::uBlas, but using the current version (3.3 or higher) of Eigen it is possible to link to "any F77 compatible BLAS or LAPACK libraries" so assuming OpenBLAS is F77 compatible, yes. See [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html) for details.

Comment: Indeed. I may add that Eigen 3.3beta1 as shipped in Ubuntu 16.04 only supports MKL; 3.3.1 indeed supports OpenBLAS. Thanks.